# Logging web.ctx

Tags: python, logging, web.py

I'm using web.py & python's logging module.

I would like to log add lots of logging. To make things more useful, I would like to add as standard the ip address of the client to the logging format (`web.ctx.ip`)

Now I 'could' do this by just writing every logging line a little like...

```
logging.debug(web.ctx.ip + "something else here")
```

... but yeah... no...

I'm not the most seasoned pythonista but am happy reading documentation. [The python documentation](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#context-info) seems to give this exact usecase as an example for when to use logging.LoggerAdapter or logging.Filter but I'm struggling to:

1. Chose whether I want to use an Adapter or a Filter?
2. and go from their examples to a working solution with web.ctx.

Would someone be able to give me a nudge? Do I need to clarify what I'm asking?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Filter, there's an example in [this post](http://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2010/09/configuring-logging-for-web.html) (not `web.py` specific, but you should be able to adapt it).

**Update:** You can use either Filter or LoggerAdapter, so pick one, like I did :-). I just picked it because there was an example handy. You really can use either, as the docs indicate.

Comment: Why should I use a Filter and not an Adapter? Reading the documentation suggests they can both do this. I don't understand why I would want one over the other.